# IBM Worklight 6.1 Mobile Pattern loading issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a worklight application with dojo mobile in IBM Worklight 6.1. When I am trying to use the mobile pattern, it is keep on loading and not showing any patterns, no matter how long I have waited for. Same issue for jquery mobile also.How can i resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: What's the problem with this question? Anyone got the question or not. Or do you guys can able to see the UI Pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the browser doesn't refresh correctly the first time, as a workaround try changing the category selected to another one, then select again the category that was selected before, after that, "Loading" message disappears and you should be able to see the patterns.